# "NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined" when calling eval()

Tags: python, numpy, eval

```
x = 0
x2 = 0
f = "numpy.sin(x)"
e1 = eval(f)
e2 = eval(f, {"x":x2})
```

The line for e2 (but not e1) generates an error:

```
NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined
```

Why?

Comment: In e2, you're providing a global environment that doesn't know about numpy.

Comment: Because you are pasing a global dictionary that *doesn't have that name*... so maybe you want `eval(f, {"x":x2, "numpy":nump})`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replacing:

```
f = "numpy.sin(x)"
```

with:

```
f = "__import__('numpy').sin(x)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since in e1, you aren't overriding the globals, numpy exists. In e2, you are, so your import can't be seen by the interpreter. Just pass in numpy as a variable.

`e2 = eval(f, {'numpy': numpy, 'x':x2})`

Comment: Thanks but that still leads to "NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined". I solved my problem by replacing "numpy.sin(x)" with "__import__('numpy').sin(x)".